# Listing Symbols before Table of Contents

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature, amsbook

My LaTeX looks as follows (I omit somethings):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\leftmark}

\newcommand{\set}{\mathsf{Set}}
\newcommand{\grp}{\mathsf{Gr}}
\newcommand{\ab}{\mathsf{Ab}}
\newcommand{\grd}{\mathsf{Grpd}}
\newcommand{\ring}{\mathsf{Ring}}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\,.\,}\hfil}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter

\title{\textsc{AAAZZZ}}
\author{LZ}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Abstract}
The goal of this notes is to describe \ldots

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Preliminaries on A}

\chapter{Results on Z}

\appendix

\chapter{More results on Z}

\backmatter

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I want to list some symbols I defined myself (as in the code above):

```
\newcommand{\set}{\mathsf{Set}}
\newcommand{\grp}{\mathsf{Gr}}
\newcommand{\ab}{\mathsf{Ab}}
\newcommand{\grd}{\mathsf{Grpd}}
\newcommand{\ring}{\mathsf{Ring}}
```

(stands one by one for the category of sets, groups, abelian groups, groupoids, rings)in my "List of Abbreviations and Symbols" chapter (just 1 or 2 pages) before `toc`. I find some relevant ways [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147853/ensure-nomenclature-definitions-are-aligned), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54720/page-with-symbols-and-notation) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101362/construction-of-a-notation-page-in-memoir-document-class), but none works in my situation, using either `nomencl` or `glossaries`. How to adapt at least one of them to make it work?

One more question: in my situation as above, how to use French and possible other languages with accents (in the English text), like "étale, Ngô Bảo Châu" (rather than using \'etale etc. each time, because I use that quite often)?

Comment: I would just use \section*{List of Symbols} and a tabular or itemize, unless you want page numbers (first usage?) added.

Comment: For `étale, Ngô Bảo Châu`, I type them in directly and compile with xelatex. The default font (Latin Modern Roman) already has the characters. Otherwise, load a desired (system, truetype) font using `fontspec` package.

Comment: @Cicada If I type them in directly then they appear weird in pdf, I don't know why. I'm using the above codes in texstudio on Mac. I expect to load only some simple packages, I tried quite a lot but failed always.

Comment: How do you compile? xelatex or pdflatex? For languages, `polyglossia` or `babel` packages, with xelatex. If you have to use `pdflatex`, fonts and accented letters become very laborious. `pdflatex` does not know Unicode.

Comment: I think there is only one way (only one icon) to compile in texstudio (or I only know one way to compile in texstudio on Mac).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235245/where-do-i-find-the-xelatex-engine-on-texstudio